# How to increase number in php if starting value is 0

Tags: php

I am getting issue when increasing number.

For example:

```
 $r = 000123 //Integer
```

Now i want

```
 $r = 000124
```

I have try with multiple way.. but i didn't get the result. because of starting with 000.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try:

```php
$r = 000123
$r++
```

Comment: No, getting wrong output..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
$num = "00000123";

// get number without zero prefix
preg_match('/(?!0+)\d+/', $num, $match);

// increase by 1
$match[0]++;

// add zero prefix
$newNum = sprintf('%08d', $match[0]);

var_dump($newNum);
```

Comment: i want without string.. my value in integer..

Like" $num =00001234;

I have try with your code without string.. getting error.

Comment: i think 000123 is not valid integer. Try dump this. You can retype to string $num = (string) 0001234;

Comment: not working. let me check other way..

Comment: without string is binary it is not a number. It will not work.